# Find the poles and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Find the poles and residues of $\frac{z \ln(z)}{(z^2+1)(z-c)}$, where $c$ is a real positive constant.

I've found the poles to be $z=i$,  $-i$ and $c$. These are simple poles. How do I now calculate the residues?

Comment: Familiar with formula for residue?? You have residue of $f$ at a simple pole $a$ as $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} (x-a)f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple poles it is very easy. For example, and choosing the main branch for the complex logarithm:

$$\text{Res}_{z=-i}f=\lim_{z\to -i}(z+i)\frac{z\log z}{(z+i)(z-i)(z-c)}=\frac{(-i)\log(-i)}{(-2i)(-i-c)}=\frac{\frac{3\pi i}2}{-2(c+i)}=$$

$$=\frac{3\pi i}{4(c+i)}=3\pi\frac{1+ci}{4|c+i|^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

For residues at $c$, follow the same method as above.This gives an answer of 
$$\frac{c \log(c)}{(c+i)(c-i)}.$$